# Delphi TDBGrid inserts new record on tab press

Tags: delphi, vcl, rad-studio, tdbgrid

Sometimes when the user presses the tab key and it's not in the last column in a TDBGrid it creates a new row and sets the linked DataSet state to dsInsert. I cannot understand why it happens nor avoid it.

Comment: Sounds like you might have a call to `Application.ProcessMessages` elsewhere in your code.  The re-entrancy that APM allows can be the source of problems like this.

Comment: Show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).